# OpenMPI: ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openmpi

I've been at it for days but could not solve my problem.

I am running:
`mpiexec -hostfile ~/machines -nolocal -pernode mkdir -p $dstpath` where $dstpath points to current directory and "machines" is a file containing:

`node01
node02
node03
node04`

This is the error output:

```
Failed to parse XML input with the minimalistic parser. If it was not
generated by hwloc, try enabling full XML support with libxml2.
[node01:06177] [[6421,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 891
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[node01:06177] 1 more process has sent help message help-errmgr-base.txt / failed-daemon-launch
[node01:06177] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
Failed to parse XML input with the minimalistic parser. If it was not
generated by hwloc, try enabling full XML support with libxml2.
[node01:06181] [[6417,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 891
```

I have 4 machines, node01 to node04. In order to log into these 4 nodes, I have to first log in to node00. I am trying to run some distributed graph functions. The graph software is installed in node01 and is supposed to be synchronised to the other nodes using mpiexec.

What I've done:

1. Made sure all passwordless login are setup, every machine can ssh to any other machine with no issues.
2. Have a hostfile in the home directory.
3. echo $PATH gives `/home/myhome/bin:/home/myhome/.local/bin:/usr/include/openmpi:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
4. echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives
   `/usr/lib/openmpi/lib`

This has previously worked before, but it just suddenly started giving these errors. I got my administrator to install fresh machines but it still gave such errors. I've tried doing it one node at a time but it gave the same errors. I'm not entirely familiar with command line at all so please give me some suggestions. I've tried reinstalling OpenMPI from source and from `sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin`. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am having like the same exact problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, it disappeared when I use IP numbers instead of node names in the machinefile. Don't really get it, hostnames are defined in /etc/hosts on all the nodes.

Answer (score -2):

You should focus on fixing:

> Failed to parse XML input with the minimalistic parser. If it was not
>   generated by hwloc, try enabling full XML support with libxml2.
>   [node01:06177] [[6421,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 891

Comment: Could you elaborate?